# R 3.1.0 - Determining Plot Sizes

Tags: r, graph, plot, size, latex

I'm plotting three graphs in 2 columns in R where the first two graphs are in the first row and the second one in the third row over both columns: (the third row is for the legend)

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), heights=c(2, 2, 0.75));
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4));

----plot commands ---- (plot.xts)
```

I do this with another set of three graphs and the same settings, but when including the graphs as `.eps` in LaTeX, the second one is much bigger than the first, i.e. the first one fits in my document, the second is too big. I would scale the figure in Latex, but that changes the font size as well. The left and right margins of my LaTeX document are both 3.5cm, so I need two .eps with no more than that width as I don't want to rescale it in Latex, as rescaling changes the font size of the first graph stronger than of the first graph (I don't know why given that the unscaled font sizes are equal).

Any ideas? I guess I just don't really get the way R determines the plot size.

Comment: It would really help if you included a small reproducible example. Try making up a small sample data set, and show us the complete code of how your are plotting it. It would also help if you showed us the LaTeX code (but only a minimal example -- just big enough to show us the problem).

Comment: the size of the graphic will be set by the device (postscript here).

Comment: It's a good idea to show the actual command you use to write out the eps file. As @baptiste mentioned, it's the graphics device that sets the size, not the plot command generally.